# Clip features based on map sheet?

Tags: arcpy, clip

I'm quite new to python and hoping for some assistance with a script.

I have a shapefile covering over 100 map sheets and would like to clip the data from this shapefile to the area of each map sheet. I have used a separate script to create a personal geodatabase named for each map sheet and each map sheet clip will be saved as a feature class in the corresponding personal geodatabase.
I know I need to query for each map sheet to perform the clip, but am unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: The green grid is a feature class and the underlying polygons is the shapefile?

Comment: @BERA yes, the grid is a feature class

Comment: Do you want to create a new geodatabase for each clip or is it ok to put them all in one? How do you want to name the outputs, is there an attribute in the grid feature class that can be used?

Comment: @BERA each clip will have the same name "RESULTS", but each needs to go in to its own personal geodatabase named for the mapsheet, which is the only attribute in the grid feature class: "map_tile"

Comment: For questions that seek help with code please always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import arcpy,os

shapefile=r'C:\folder\shapefile.shp' #Change to match your data
clip_grid=r'C:\filegeodatabase.gdb\grid' #Change to match your data
output_folder=r'C:\outputfolder' #Change to match your data

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(clip_grid,['SHAPE@','map_tile']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(out_folder_path=output_folder, out_name=row[1]+'.mdb')
        arcpy.env.workspace=os.path.join(output_folder,row[1]+'.mdb')
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features=shapefile, clip_features=row[0], out_feature_class='RESULTS')
```

I'm using the [SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) to iterate over each of the grid features.